# Rpm’s fall to 800 when decelerating from second gear into first

Tags: honda, transmission, accord, rpm, transmission-fluid

A 2004 Honda accord coupe exl’s rpm falls to 800 then back to normal when decelerating from 2nd gear back into first. The transmission fluid still has visible color to it and nothing else on the dipstick when vehicle is at operating (and has operated) temperature. Should I change the fluid or what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Not knowing which engine you have in it, 800rpm *sounds normal*. What is it usually? I also take it the vehicle is an automatic? If so, is this during normal operation or are you forcing the shifts (manual shifting an automatic)?

Comment: What speed are you dropping to 1st? It's not something I'd normally be doing during deceleration [auto/paddle or stick] only when virtually stopped & preparing to go again. How many gears? Low 'gear count' autos, 3- or 4-speed, probably wouldn't do this until you accelerate, just to be sure. A 7- or 8-speed may not drop to 1st at all unless you stop. Also… petrol or diesel? 800 is a tad high for a diesel idle, OK for a petrol [depending on engine size/cylinder count]

Comment: tbh, if this is a manual & you insist on dropping through the box during deceleration,  especially the big gap to 1st, maybe you need to learn how to rev-match, or at least blip the throttle as you shift, even if it's a bit vague. A last thought - if it's an auto, does it have sport/standard/comfort settings? Sport will demand you rev match [or would do it for you - you'd hear it if so], standard will still do engine braking but be less driver-demanding, comfort may not engine brake at all, relying on driver brake pressure entirely.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.